# git project folder disapears in the middle of editing inside VM

Tags: windows, git, ubuntu-16.04

I'm using ubuntu 16.04 virtual machine, vmware 12.5.6, on a windows PC. I have a python project that I work on using git on the virtual machine. However, sometimes after running and testing the code in terminal, everything in the project folder including `.git/` disappears.

Has anyone run into this bug?

Comment: Are you sure its disappeared and not just hidden? And are you sure that something in python script is not causing that behavior?

Comment: @Ayushya Yes, I double-checked that there were no hidden files in the directory. I don't think there is an issue with the python script - it is not deleting or doing anything funny with file paths.